# Stackoverflow like pagination helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, helper

Is there any pagination helper like stackoverflow in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.com) they use a PaginatedList helper which, as the name suggests, provides a paginated list of IQueryable.